# Intermittent javascript download issue

Tags: apache-2.2, corruption, host

I posted this question on stackoverflow, then it was suggested I try here, as it seems it could be a server issue.

After having no issues on my development xampp box, once I put my site live onto my host I get an intermittant issue whereby some of my HTTP requests are not completing properly. Whilst watching in firebug net console, the request completes with an 0200, but the file, usually a js and sometimes an image file, is either corrupt in the case of js, or not there or incomplete in the case of an image.

This only happens when I am logged into my CMS dashboard, and usually when I am using the inline edit function. I am using the FuelCMS.

In this case, the page makes 51 HTTP requests at a total of 1.7mb.

The file that comes through as corrupt seems to always 'stutter' and take >5s to download. (Could this be related to the keep-alive setting in the HTTP response, which has a timeout of 5seconds?) ALTHOUGH, it has happened VERY rarely when no files have been over >5s, and also has failed to happen when a file has taken >5s. So not sure if this can be counted as a pattern.

It happens in about 1-2 out of every ten page loads.

There is no pattern to which files are corrupt, or to how they are corrupted.

Server Details:

Apache version  2.2.17
PHP version     5.2.17
Architecture    x86_64
Operating system    linux
Kernel version  2.6.18-194.32.1.el5

So there you go. I am baffled! If anyone has any experience of this, or any ideas as to what it could be, or any further diagnostics I can try, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

ADDITIONAL:

Here is the relevant line from the access log for the file that was corrupted. Looks like nothing intoward to me. There is nothing in the server error logs.

XX.XXX.XXX.XX - - [15/Sep/2011:11:49:12 +0100] "GET /fuel/modules/fuel/assets/js/editors/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?c=943948800 HTTP/1.1" 200 335469 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2"

Comment: Please post the relevant lines from all log files (error.log / access.log).

Comment: Hmmm, nothing in the error logs. Also, can't access the access logs as they seem to be incompatabile with my 64-bit machine. Have contacted the host about this and the issue generally. Will upload relevant parts of logs when I get them.